# Load an sqlite database from a void* data blob

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've got an SQL database loading from a path using sqlite_open_v2() in C++.

I need now to load it from a data blob.  I've got a `void*` to the start of the data.  Is there a way to load it?

Comment: [`sqlite3_column_blob`/`sqlite3_column_bytes`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)

Comment: Will you be opening it read-write? If so, how is SQLite to know how to reallocate the allocation pointed to by the `void*` if you add more data?

Comment: It would be read-only.  But I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no mechanism to access the raw data of an in-memory database.

You have to write the data to a temporary file, and open that.